# show only specified area of image on iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios5, cgaffinetransform

[image: By displaying all the boxes one by one in sequence a Dancing Girl can be animated.]

I want to create an animation from a single image. Typically by displaying cropped part of image on the output canvas/box.
Should I use CIcrop or anyother techniques and idea to do it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use cocos2D framework you can use something like "flip book animations".

This method is quite well described in the book [PJ Cabrera - Beginning iPhone Games Development 2010](http://www.apress.com/9781430225997) in **chapter 4**: "She Shoots, She Hits, She Scores!"

You can also find source code of ch.4 in Source Code/Downloads tab